# caching causing my django app incorrectly ommit updates to webpage

Tags: python, html, css, django

I am using a Mac and am trying to make a django app.
I have tried to update my webpage in my django app with the following strategies:

inserting the following (which was totally missing from my settings- using django 1.8.3) into my settings.py:

```
     CACHES = {
       'default': {
         'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.dummy.DummyCache',
    }
 }
```

I tried right clicking the page on chrome and 'inspecting the element' to 'disable caching' under the 'Network' tab.

I tried updating the 'Parental settings' on Safari: System Preferences> Parental control> clicking the lock button in the bottom left corner to unlock.

I have also tried specify the date of my last save of the CSS file in my HTML

```
     <link href ="{% static "css/temp.css"? Wednesday 10th of February 2016%}" rel = "stylesheet" type="text.css"/>
```

But the page just won't update... Any tips?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "update?" Are you trying to add this stylesheet to your project?

Comment: Seriously how is nobody else having this problem??? How can you make changes to the html page if it stubbornly sticks to an old template and won't show newly input changes???

Comment: I have imported and added a never_cache tag to each of the views but the html page won't budge....

Comment: Are you in a development environment (i.e. `manage.py runserver`) or have you deployed to a remote server?

Comment: yes i am using "./manage.py runserver" and "python manage.py run server" and I am not using a development environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using `manage.py runserver`, you need to stop the server then restart it whenever you add new static assets. `runserver` will not collect static assets for you while running, it only does so on startup.